# Performing valueForKeyPaths against multiple keyPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Let's say I have an object with some number of properties and I load up 1000s of these objects into an array.  Next, I perform a series of `valueForKeyPaths` against these properties:

```
result.property1 = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.property1"];
result.property2 = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.property2"];
result.property3 = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.property3"];
etc...
```

Summing these properties individually seems pretty inefficient.  Is there a better way besides  fast enumerating over the properties and summing them manually?  i.e.

```
for(Foo* foo in array) {
    result.property1 += foo.property1;
    result.property2 += foo.property2;
    result.property3 += foo.property3;
}
```

Comment: The word 'seems' concerns me. Don't make assumptions about the performance characteristics of either approach (or about how important this piece of code is to your program's performance). Profile it if it worries you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KVC requires keys to be strings:

> A key is a string that identifies a specific property of an object. Typically, a key corresponds to the name of an accessor method or instance variable in the receiving object. Keys must use ASCII encoding, begin with a lowercase letter, and may not contain whitespace.

So the answer as far as I know is unfortunately you can't do this with `valueForKeyPath:` you would have to manually do it or enumerate over it.